A detail in the proof that every irreducible closed set $X$ is birational to a hypersurface of some affine space.
I am reading Shavalievich's Basic Algebraic Geometry. In section 3.3 of chapter 1, he showed that every irreducible closed set $X$ is birational to a hypersurface of some affine space. Here is the sketch:
First, $k(X)/k$ is a finitely generated field extension over an algebraically closed field. By some arguments in field theory (proposition A7 in the book):
$$ k(X)=k(z_1,\dots,z_{d+1})$$
where $z_1,\dots,z_d$ are algebraically indepedent over $k$, $z_{d+1}$ is algebraic, separable over $k(z_1,\dots,z_d)$, and:
$$ f(z_1,\dots,z_{d+1})=0$$
with $f\in k[x_1,\dots,x_{d+1}]$ irreducible and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{d+1}}\neq 0$.
Consider $Y:=\mathbb{V}(f)\subseteq \mathbb{A}^{d+1}$, he claimed that:
$$ k(Y)=\mathrm{Frac}(k[x_1,\dots,x_{d+1}]/f)\cong k(X)$$
Now I want to justify this claim.
My attempt: By the universal property of fractional field, it suffices to show that there exists an (ring) embedding:
$$ k[x_1,\dots,x_{d+1}]/f\hookrightarrow k(z_1,\dots,z_{d+1})$$
It suffices to show that the evaluation map:
$$ \begin{aligned}
 k[x_1,\dots,x_{d+1}]&\rightarrow k(z_1,\dots,z_{d+1})\\
x_i&\mapsto z_i
\end{aligned}$$
has kernel $\left\langle f\right\rangle$. But I then get stuck and have no idea how to proceed.
Edit: It seems that we can proceed in this way:
Suppose $g(z_1,\dots,z_{d+1})=0$ and $f\nmid g$. Then by Guass lemma:
$$ \gcd_{k[x_1,\dots,x_{d+1}]} (f,g)=1\Rightarrow \gcd_{k(x_1,\dots,x_d)[x_{d+1}]} (f,g)=1$$
Therefore (after clearing the denominators):
$$ 1= pf+qg\Rightarrow r=p'f+q'g$$
where $0\neq r\in k[x_1,\dots,x_d]$. Substituting $x_i=z_i$ yields a non-trivial algebraic relation of $z_1,\dots,z_d$, contradiction.
Is the above argument a valid one? Or are there any easier way to show this claim? Thanks!

I think that this is valid. Here is an easier method ; Look at the composition $k[x_1,\dots,x_{d+1}] \hookrightarrow k(x_1,\dots,x_d)[x_{d+1}] \rightarrow k(z_1,\dots,z_{d+1})$. The ring $k(x_1,\dots,x_d)[x_{d+1}]$ is a PID, and almost by definition, the kernel of the map $k(x_1,\dots,x_d)[x_{d+1}] \rightarrow k(z_1,\dots,z_{d+1})$ is $(f)$ (as $f$ was chosen irreducible). Thus the kernel of the composition is again $(f)$ (the ideal in $k[x_1,\dots,x_{d+1}]$ this time).

@EnguerrandMoulinier that looks like an answer to me - please consider recording this as such below.

@KReiser Okay, I recorded it as an answer. I didn't think it was worth it but I take your advice

@EnguerrandMoulinier there are a number of reasons to post answers instead comments. See here on Meta for instance. Thanks for posting an answer!

I think that this is valid. Here is an easier method ; Look at the composition $k[x_1,\dots,x_{d+1}]\hookrightarrow k(x_1,\dots,x_d)[x_{d+1}] \rightarrow k(z_1,\dots,z_{d+1})$, the latter one sending $x_i$ to $z_i$.
The ring $k(x_1,\dots,x_d)[x_{d+1}]$ is a PID, and almost by definition, the kernel of the map $k(x_1,\dots,x_d)[x_{d+1}] \rightarrow k(z_1,\dots,z_{d+1})$ is $(f)$ in $k(x_1,\dots,x_d)[x_{d+1}]$ (as $f$ was chosen irreducible). Thus the kernel of the composition is again $(f)$ (an ideal in $k[x_1,\dots,x_{d+1}]$ this time).

Thank you! I am a bit confused, since in your proof you do not need $z_1,\dots,z_{d}$ to be algebraically independent, right? But in my proof I use this essentially. So I wonder if this claim is true regardless of the algebraically independence of ${z_1,\dots,z_d}$?
Edit: Fine, I find that we still need this condition to show that the kernel of the map $k(x_1,\dots,x_d)[x_{d+1}]\rightarrow k(z_1,\dots,z_{d+1})$ to be $(f)$.
